# Unable to open links in symfony apostrophe cms

Tags: symfony1, content-management-system, apostrophe

I did a fresh install of Apostrophe plugin in Symfony exactly following the steps in the apostrophe manual. Without modifying the vhost.sample. Only edited /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file to include ServerName localhost. Now I am able to get the index page perfectly. But unable to open any links. Gives a page not found error. Mod_Rewrite is enabled. I am new to Symfony & Apostrophe.

Comment: Please post your relevant portion of `httpd.conf` and the a sample url that is tried to be opened